# MySQL function to return multiple Ints from String

Tags: java, mysql, function, stored-procedures

I want to pass in the string such as "1,3,5,7,9,0,3" which comes from a Java method into a function and for the function to return each value separated by the comma as an Int which will then be used later in a stored procedure (shown below).

```
CREATE PROCEDURE updateLastModifiedDate(IN p_classId VARCHAR(21844), IN p_timestamp VARCHAR(21844))
    BEGIN
        SET @query = CONCAT ('UPDATE class SET LastModifiedDate = ',p_timestamp,' WHERE ClassId IN (', p_classId ,')');
        PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
        EXECUTE stmt;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
    END //
DELIMITER ;
```

How would I write the function?

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: .....How do I write the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, the input to the function is  a COMMA SEPARATED string. But MySql does not include a built-in function to split a COMMA SEPARATED string (comma is just an example for a separator).

You have mentioned the input as  "1,3,5,7,9,0,3". That means, the count of items is 7. This count Needs to be Constant. I can give you as example but the Count of items should be Constant always.

Also a mysql function can return a single value only. So you have to call the Procedure from within the function only (after splitting values).

Am giving you a [mysql function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html) with the assumption that, the input string contains 7 items **always** And the separator used was **comma**. You have have to modify the function otherwise.

```
DELIMITER @@

CREATE FUNCTION getCustomerFullName(commaSeparatedString VARCHAR(256))
RETURNS INT
BEGIN
  DECLARE value1 INT DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE value2 INT DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE value3 INT DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE value4 INT DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE value5 INT DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE value6 INT DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE value7 INT DEFAULT 0;

  IF NOT commaSeparatedString IS NULL
    THEN
          SELECT LENGTH(commaSeparatedString) - LENGTH(REPLACE(commaSeparatedString, ',', '')) INTO @commaCount;

          IF  @commaCount = 0
            THEN
                 RETURN 0;  
          ELSE
            SET value1 = REPLACE(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(commaSeparatedString, ',', 1),LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(commaSeparatedString, ',', 0)) + 1), ',', '');
            SET value2 = REPLACE(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(commaSeparatedString, ',', 2),LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(commaSeparatedString, ',', 1)) + 1), ',', '');
            SET value3 = REPLACE(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(commaSeparatedString, ',', 3),LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(commaSeparatedString, ',', 2)) + 1), ',', '');
            SET value4 = REPLACE(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(commaSeparatedString, ',', 4),LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(commaSeparatedString, ',', 3)) + 1), ',', '');
            SET value5 = REPLACE(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(commaSeparatedString, ',', 5),LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(commaSeparatedString, ',', 4)) + 1), ',', '');
            SET value6 = REPLACE(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(commaSeparatedString, ',', 6),LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(commaSeparatedString, ',', 5)) + 1), ',', '');
            SET value7 = REPLACE(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(commaSeparatedString, ',', 7),LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(commaSeparatedString, ',', 6)) + 1), ',', '');

        END IF;
  END IF; 

  CALL updateLastModifiedDate(value1, value2, value3, value4, value5, value6, value7);

  RETURN 1;
END;
@@

DELIMITER ;
```

Courtesy:

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#c7359
- http://dinushasblog.blogspot.in/2010/12/split-strings-in-mysql.html
- http://blog.fedecarg.com/2009/02/22/mysql-split-string-function/

Comment: Thanks for a great answer, if the count of the items was not always a known number would it be possible to modify the function to suit?

Comment: The count of the items should be constant for my knowledge. The main headache is the absence of a built-in split function in mysql.